# Change Hash to array of arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Let's say i have a hash

```
 {:facebook=>0.0, :twitter=>10.0, :linkedin=>6.0, :youtube=>8.0}
```

Now i want it to change to an array like

```
[[Facebook,0.0],[Twitter,10.0],[Linkedin,6.0],[Youtube,8.0]]
```

I can use a logic to extract and change it in to array, but i was just wondering if there could be any defined methods in ruby which i can use to implement the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sites = {:facebook => 0.0, :twitter => 10.0, :linkedin => 6.0, :youtube => 8.0}
sites.map { |key, value| [Object.const_get(key.to_s.capitalize), value] }
```

Answer (score 32):

You can use [to_a](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

```
{:facebook=>0.0, :twitter=>10.0, :linkedin=>6.0, :youtube=>8.0}.to_a
```

returns

```
[[:facebook, 0.0], [:twitter, 10.0], [:linkedin, 6.0], [:youtube, 8.0]]
```

This won't automatically convert your symbols to constants though, you will have to use [map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (and [const_get](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Module.html#method-i-const_get)) for that.

```
{:facebook=>0.0, :twitter=>10.0, :linkedin=>6.0, :youtube=>8.0}.map{|k,v| [Kernel.const_get(k.to_s.capitalize), v]}
```

Outputs

```
[[Facebook,0.0],[Twitter,10.0],[Linkedin,6.0],[Youtube,8.0]]
```

Answer (score 7):

`your_hash.to_a`

is the answer. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a

Answer (score 6):

Just wrap your hash in [] and add asterisks before hash.

```
[*{:facebook=>0.0, :twitter=>10.0, :linkedin=>6.0, :youtube=>8.0}]
```

Comment: I think that this is kinda crypt solution. Calling to_a is much more readable :)